# Gap on the right side with horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal scroll because there is space on the right side of the page after a certain width. I can't seem to fix it. I'm guessing it's either the carousel or the bodyimg causing the problem. Can someone help pint to me what i'm supposed to do and where? Additionally i have a .btn:hover that isn't working in CSS, I would like to change the default button hover styles but i don't know how either, if someone could point out how to do that it'd be great too!

EDIT: I've realised this is happening on my other pages as well, so it might not be my carousel but my footer or nav?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
 margin: 0;
}


.nopadding{

 padding: 0;
}


.navbar {
  background: url(../images/mainnav.png) no-repeat top center;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navspace {
  padding: 30px 46px 30px 46px;
}

.navposition {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
}

.icon-bar {

}

.thumbnails {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 150px;
}

#myCarousel {
 width: 980px;
 height: 654px;
 bottom: 25px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.carousel-control {
 height: 600px;
}


.banner {
 background: url(../images/banner1.png) no-repeat top center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 980px;
 height: 654px;
 left: 110px;
 bottom: 30px;
 background-size:100% auto;
 

}

.banner p {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 top: 440px;
 left: 20px;

}

.banner h1 {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 left: 20px;
 top: 420px;
}

.bodyimg {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.bodytext1 {
 color: #ff8300;
}

.bodytext2 {
 color: #ff8300;
 width: 160px;
 margin-top: 37px;
}

.bodytext3 {
 color: #ff8300;
 margin-top: 60px
}

.bodytext4 {
 color: #ff8300;
 margin-top: 60px
}

.socialpadding {
 padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 position: relative;
}

.centersocial {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
}

.contactinfo {

  color: #ff8300;
  margin: 200px 0px 0px auto;
  left: 50px;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.formarea {

  background:  url(../images/formbg.png) no-repeat ;
  width: 400px;
  height: 484px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.formlabel {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fcb972; 
  border-color: #ff9300;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-color: #ff9300;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.btn:onclick {
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-color: #ff9300;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.messageform {
  height: 50px;
}

.google-maps {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 75%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
.google-maps iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% ;
        height: 100% ;
    }

.foot {

 background: url(../images/footer.png) no-repeat bottom center;
 height: 50px;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
   right: 0;

  
}


footer {
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 350px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 10px;

 

}




@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    #myCarousel.carousel {
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    }

    .navbar { 
  background-image: none; 
  background-color: #ff8300; 
  } 

    .findus { 

  margin: 0 auto;
  } 

  .centersocial { 
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: ;
  } 

  .bodytext4 { 
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto 5px auto;
  } 

  .bodytext3 { 
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 60px auto 5px auto;
  } 

  .foot { 
  background-image: none; 
  background-color: #ff8300; 
  } 
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container nopadding">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria- expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navposition">
        <li class="navspace"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li class="navspace"><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li class="navspace"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div> <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active banner">
      <p>10% off all pizzas
        <br>this weekend only</p>
      <h1>LIMITED TIME<br>ONLY</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="row thumbnails">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/bodyimg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <p class="bodytext1">
        Year 2004.<br><br>

        The warmth and comfort of wood-fired pizzas and traditional pastas over chilled drinks with friends and families became an everyday affair that started with the first Peperoni, located in Greenwood Singapore. Charming, vivacious and full of life, Peperoni Greenwood brings together food lovers from all walks of life. Including many well known and young artists whose work adorn its walls with their expressions of love and creativity. Peperoni Greenwood inspired its owners, the highly acclaimed Les Amis group, to spread the love and energy of Peperoni with the opening of new outlets across the sunny island of Singapore.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 hidden-xs">

      <p class="bodytext2">
        Peperoni has since evolved into a much-loved destination with its ‘Appetite for Life’ philosophy. This philosophy makes Peperoni more than just a restaurant, as it is a place with a mission - to bring people together, to bind relationships, and to savour life in all its delightful flavours.<br><br>

        Share moments of fun, energy and inspiration over hot pizzas and cool conversations!

      </p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">

      <p class="bodytext3">

          Check us out on our social media accounts or subscribe to our newsletter for the latest updates!

      </p>

      <div class="centersocial">

        <a href="#"><img class="socialpadding"src="images/email.png" alt=""><a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/peperonipizzeria/"><img class="socialpadding"src="images/insta.png" alt=""><a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/peperonipizzeria/"><img class="socialpadding" src="images/fb.png" alt=""><a>


      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">

      <p class="bodytext4">
        Feel free to come explore our outlets

      </p>

      <a href="locations.html"><img class="findus img-responsive" src="images/findus.png" alt=""><a>


    </div>
  </div>

  
</div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **Please** *DO NOT* copy/paste all your code here, instead your should add a working fiddle or snippet!

Comment: Thank you, didn't know what fiddle or snippet was but I've just added it, without the images i'm using tho.

Comment: for which element you set `certain width` ?

Comment: not quite sure what you're asking for, but i set widths for the navbar and carousel. Navbar max-width: 980px and width: 980px for the carousel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `left: 50%` property you have declared on `.centersocial` for the *@media breakpoint* `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)`, eg:

```
.centersocial {
  position: relative;
  /* left: 50%; remove this and consider alternatives which are responsive */
}
```

Additionally, declare `max-width: 100%` on the following selectors:

```
.row, #myCarousel, .container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: url(../images/mainnav.png) no-repeat top center;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navspace {
  padding: 30px 46px 30px 46px;
}

.navposition {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
}

.icon-bar {}

.thumbnails {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#myCarousel {
  width: 980px;
  height: 654px;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-control {
  height: 600px;
}

.banner {
  background: url(../images/banner1.png) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 980px;
  height: 654px;
  left: 110px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.banner p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 440px;
  left: 20px;
}

.banner h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 20px;
  top: 420px;
}

.bodyimg {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.bodytext1 {
  color: #ff8300;
}

.bodytext2 {
  color: #ff8300;
  width: 160px;
  margin-top: 37px;
}

.bodytext3 {
  color: #ff8300;
  margin-top: 60px
}

.bodytext4 {
  color: #ff8300;
  margin-top: 60px
}

.socialpadding {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.centersocial {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.contactinfo {
  color: #ff8300;
  margin: 200px 0px 0px auto;
  left: 50px;
}


/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */

.formarea {
  background: url(../images/formbg.png) no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 484px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.formlabel {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fcb972;
  border-color: #ff9300;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ff9300;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.btn:onclick {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ff9300;
  color: #ff8300;
}

.messageform {
  height: 50px;
}

.google-maps {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.google-maps iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foot {
  background: url(../images/footer.png) no-repeat bottom center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 350px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #myCarousel.carousel {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff8300;
  }
  .findus {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .centersocial {
    position: relative;
  }
  .bodytext4 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 100px auto 5px auto;
  }
  .bodytext3 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 60px auto 5px auto;
  }
  .foot {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff8300;
  }
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
  display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}

/* additional */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row, #myCarousel, .container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container nopadding">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria- expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navposition">
          <li class="navspace"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li class="navspace"><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
          <li class="navspace"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active banner">
            <p>10% off all pizzas
              <br>this weekend only</p>
            <h1>LIMITED TIME<br>ONLY</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row thumbnails">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/bodyimg.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <p class="bodytext1">
          Year 2004.<br><br> The warmth and comfort of wood-fired pizzas and traditional pastas over chilled drinks with friends and families became an everyday affair that started with the first Peperoni, located in Greenwood Singapore. Charming, vivacious
          and full of life, Peperoni Greenwood brings together food lovers from all walks of life. Including many well known and young artists whose work adorn its walls with their expressions of love and creativity. Peperoni Greenwood inspired its owners,
          the highly acclaimed Les Amis group, to spread the love and energy of Peperoni with the opening of new outlets across the sunny island of Singapore.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 hidden-xs">

        <p class="bodytext2">
          Peperoni has since evolved into a much-loved destination with its ‘Appetite for Life’ philosophy. This philosophy makes Peperoni more than just a restaurant, as it is a place with a mission - to bring people together, to bind relationships, and to savour
          life in all its delightful flavours.<br><br> Share moments of fun, energy and inspiration over hot pizzas and cool conversations!

        </p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">

        <p class="bodytext3">

          Check us out on our social media accounts or subscribe to our newsletter for the latest updates!

        </p>

        <div class="centersocial">

          <a href="#"><img class="socialpadding" src="images/email.png" alt="">
            </a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/peperonipizzeria/"><img class="socialpadding" src="images/insta.png" alt="">
                </a>
                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/peperonipizzeria/"><img class="socialpadding" src="images/fb.png" alt="">
                    </a>


        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">

        <p class="bodytext4">
          Feel free to come explore our outlets

        </p>

        <a href="locations.html"><img class="findus img-responsive" src="images/findus.png" alt="">
          </a>


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, the horizontal scroll bar is gone now, but things are no longer centered, and the carousel does not extend all the way to the right edge of the browser in mobile. My nav is also out of place in desktop now. I think I used the left: 50%; to center it before.

Comment: @LukeSciberras I mentioned specifically that this rule (`left: 50%`) should be removed (because it is one of the contributing factors to the horizontal overflow), consider better alternatives to centering this element (there are many). The issue of the question has been addressed, and that is: *rectifying the horizontal overflow*. If that has been adequately accomplished you should mark this answer correct and consider opening a new question which addresses the other issues you've pointed out - they are separate concerns and should be addressed in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `width` of certain elements set their `max-width` and set their `width` to 100%.

> The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.
>   This prevents the value of the width property from becoming larger than max-width.

for example on the next class you should apply the `max-width` instead of `width`:

```
 #myCarousel {
 max-width: 980px;
 width:100%;
 ......
 .....
}
```

and

```
 .banner {
  background: url(../images/banner1.png) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 980px;/*this would be applied only when the width of the user screen is bigger then 920px*/
  width:100%;/* once the user screen in equal or smaller then 980px the widht of the element would be 100%  */
  .......
  }
```

Comment: Hi, i've done that, and it has seemed to work for most of the breakpoints until mobile, where the gap on the right is even bigger now.

Comment: that mast be the `.banner {left: 110px;}` and check the absolute  position

Answer (score 0):

Some advices :

- use a editor to format your html code, it helps pointing out some errors
- provide a online version of your code to help people to interact with, at the moment your code needs a bootstrap.min.css and botstrap.min.js but no version is provided. Version is important to reproduce exact same situation
- provide images or similar images : logo, banner1.png, formbg.ng, mainnav.png, footer.png, chicago.png, etc... are missing, without them we can't be sure that doesn't participate in your issue. (You are using W3C example, point it out)

Issues:

- HTML code has missing  `div` tag
- Bootstrap version is unknown (latest 3.3.7 ?)
- some `id` contains \n (bs-example-navbar-\ncollapse-1)
- some `</li>` exists without `<li>`
- use of "row" class within a "row" class. Please refer to bootstrap to understand how to use "row" div and "col-xx-yy" div. You can't use row within row without specifying a col-xx-yy before
- missing `</body></html>` at the end of the file

For your issue about width and scroll:

- css explicitly specify a carrousel width : `#myCarousel { width: 980px;`. It doesn't fit with bootstrap media queries and get scroll bars since you ve a fixed width.

To resolve this issue:

- use a `100%` width if possible, it will stick to viewport size
- use media queries if you want a specific size for each media since you specify also a `654px` height

Or just stick with default Carrousel (since you took this example from W3C) and do not try to set a specific size (h/w) for it. Bootstrap already adapt image size based on viewport size. Provide only same image size.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'm pretty bad at all this, I'm just a (design) student that has to learn basic web development! I use Sublime right now, it's what my school taught us to use.
I've added max-width: 980px; and width:100%; to some of my elements but I still get the gap in XS (I presume, when i reduce the width of my browser all the way). I wanted to set a fixed height because I wanted my carousel to take over the whole screen in mobile instead of scaling down.

Comment: Sublime is able to reformat code (search for sublime text format code).  
If you want the whole page in mobile version you should know your mobile target since there are multiple devices and device size (+portrait/paysage mode) + avoid using specific height but use dedicated  images size. 
If you want some ideas on how it's done on other websites between desktop, tablet and mobile there is a website with a list of views here : https://mediaqueri.es/